# Javascript object constructor jQuery getJSON setting property fails

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, oop

I am trying to create a Javascript Object where the constructor sets the data property with a callback function using `$.getJSON();`

I am new to Javascript and eventually came up with this but I keep getting `undefined` when I execute `getData()`.

Any pointers would be  great and prefer don't want to use `async: false`.

```
// Class
function DS(url) {

    // Variable
    this.data = undefined;

    // Constructor
    this.init = function(that, url) {
        var self = that;
        return $.getJSON(url, function(data) {
            self.setData(data);
        });
    }(this, url)

    // Callback / Setter
    this.setData = function(data) {
        this.data = data;
        return this;
    }

    // Getter
    this.getData = function() {
        return this.data;
    }
};

var ds = new DS("/your/awesome/endpoint.json");
console.log(ds.getData()); // gives undefined
```

Answer (score 0):

`$.getJSON` is an async function and your `ds.getData()` called before the callback function of `$.getJSON` you need to move the function `ds.getData()` in the callback

```
this.init = function(that, url) {
    var self = that;
    return $.getJSON(url, function(data) {
        self.setData(data);
        console.log(self.getData()); // Here is the fix
    });
}(this, url)
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/unBjJ/2/